# How to find placeholder value in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, getattribute

I need to verify whether placeholder/helper text is displayed for a field.
In this example it is Min. $50.00 
I don't see any placeholder/helper text  attribute defined inside the div tags.
My field looks like [image] . Displayed amount (in this example $50.00) is dynamic.
Code for the above field looks like

```
<div  class="unit" style="padding-left:32px;">
        <input id="Amount" type="text" class="inputAlign optionalHintText" size="18" maxlength="30"/>
        <div id="sharesValueForPercent" class="TextMd"></div> 
</div>
```

I tried different ways to get the text (Min$50.00). Can someone help me on this. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the placeholder text i.e. **$50.00** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.inputAlign.optionalHintText#Amount")).getAttribute("value"));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='inputAlign optionalHintText' and @id='Amount']")).getAttribute("value"));
  ```

Comment: I am able to get the value. Thank you so much.